# Why after importing openpyxl is delete_rows not recognized as a function?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to use a simple `delete_rows` line to clear some data our of a sheet after importing via `openpyxl`, but the function is unrecognized by my Visual Studio Code.

When I use `from openpyxl import load_workbook`, the `load_workbook` text is grayed out like it's not recognized, but my `openpyxl.load_workbook` line is working. For some reason when I type out `delete_rows` the function is not autofilled like it's not being recognized.

Tried `pip install openpyxl`, but I already have the latest.

Answer (score 0):

`delete_rows` is a method of the `Worksheet` object ([docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows)), not a function like `load_workbook`, so you do not need to import it, just call it on a `Worksheet` (see also [this demo page](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html)).

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("<xlsx_file_name>")
ws = wb.active

ws.delete_rows(2, 1)
```

Comment: My issue is that when I type ws.delete_rows, the "delete_rows" text doesn't change colors. So it appears it's not getting recognized as a method, but just as plain text.

Comment: Have you tried typing further, filling the arguments, finishing the program and running your script ? If this is just about how VSCode displays your code, then it's off-topic.